# How to print chart with multiple values between dates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graph, charts

I'm trying to display this kind of list on a chart:

```
[ [ Moment<2020-08-02T02:54:24+02:00>, 9.99 ],
  [ Moment<2020-08-05T21:55:33+02:00>, 10.99 ],
  [ Moment<2020-08-05T22:00:50+02:00>, 26.87 ],
  [ Moment<2020-08-06T23:43:32+02:00>, 10.99 ],
  [ Moment<2020-08-07T22:57:13+02:00>, 26.87 ],
  [ Moment<2020-08-07T23:01:20+02:00>, 9.99 ],
  [ Moment<2020-08-08T22:10:14+02:00>, 10.99 ],
  [ Moment<2020-08-08T22:12:20+02:00>, 35.83 ],
  [ Moment<2020-08-10T19:03:51+02:00>, 20.24 ],
  [ Moment<2020-08-11T17:24:39+02:00>, 10.99 ],
  [ Moment<2020-08-11T17:27:41+02:00>, 27.03 ],
  [ Moment<2020-08-13T14:04:34+02:00>, 29.54 ],
  [ Moment<2020-08-17T04:17:37+02:00>, 9.99 ],
  [ Moment<2020-08-25T04:57:57+02:00>, 10.99 ] ]
```

What I try to get is to have the x-axis separated by one day each square but keeping the fact that there can be multiple values for one day (so every point is separated by a different distance). I don't really know how to approach it, if you can give me some directions on how to start it, it would be much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a range for the x-axis, listing all the dates.
For that you can use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-range

Then loop through that range, for each day get the values from your list (by filtering for example).

It then depends on your chart library and business logic on how you'd combine multiple values per day (for example adding them) or display them individually as stacked column chart.